# How to enable wayland with nouveau in ubuntu 18.10?

Tags: nvidia, gnome, nouveau, wayland

I don't see cogwheel, so I can't logout and choose gnome on wayland. I haven't changed any configuration, so `#WaylandEnable=false` is commented in gdm config and stuff like that.

Is there a bug I can track or something I could do to make it work?

Comment: Wayland does not work with nvidia.  When Nvidia drivers are present, and the Wayland choice is offered, it switches to the i915 (integrated driver).  Do you have integrated video for Wayland to use?

Comment: @ubfan1 No, why isn't it working? It worked for me recently with proprietary driver, but I doesn't anymore (black screen when `nvidia-drm.modeset=1`).